# What are my options for a Python open source cross-platform Postgres-Compatible driver?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm not really a Python expert nor am I a Postgres expert, but here goes:

I need a good open source Postgres driver for Python.  It must be able to work cross platform with little fuss, between Windows, Mac, and Linux.  The end goal is to have it deployed to a 64 bit CentOS Linux server.

I need it to be open source, because I will need to modify it a little bit to fit our Postgres-like database.  I have already done this in the C-only world with great success and I would like to avoid rolling my own driver from scratch.

Any suggestions?

Thanks you.

Comment: What have you tried? I've usually used [pyPgSQL](http://pypgsql.sourceforge.net/). Would that work for you?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, yet, I just wanted to ask the experts.  I'm not a python or postgres guru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've used these:

- [pg8000](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pg8000) - written in pure python, therefore no compiling needed on the target platform. good if portability is an issue.
- [psycopg2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2) - written in c, therefore a bit faster then pg8000, but compiling needed for the target platform.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out pg8000 and swap in psycopg2 if need we're hurting for speed.